# Circular dependency issues with inheritance and returning instances

Tags: c++, inheritance, circular-dependency, forward-declaration

I have two classes in separate headers:

```
struct A {
    virtual B getB();
}

template<typename T>
struct Basic : public A {
}
typedef Basic<int> B;
```

Both headers need to include each other, which is not ideal due to circular dependency.
However, A::getB() returns an instance, so I can't forward declare to avoid the include, and Basic inherits A, so its the same deal there. Basic must inherit A, but A doesn't NEED the getB() function (although, it is highly preferable).
I must avoid the circular dependency, but am I going about this the wrong way?

Note: the A class will be inherited by a lot of other classes further down the line, hence why getB() is virtual. And Basic is a template class, so it's definition is inside it's header as well. getB() must return an instance (anything coming out of getB() is expected to be local to getB(), which is why it can't return a pointer nor a reference).

Answer (score 2):

do the following:

```
struct A {
    virtual B* getB();
}
```

That is, `struct A` must refer to `struct B` only through pointers. Then you can solve the issue by forward declaring `struct B` before the definition of `struct A`.

**Update After Clarification:**

You can do something like the following then:

```
template <typename> struct Basic;
typedef Basic<int> B;

struct A {
    virtual B getB();
};

template<typename T>
struct Basic : public A {

};

// definitions of member functions for struct A below here!!!
B A::getB() { B b; return b;}

int main()
{
    A a;
    B b;

   return 0;
}
```

Have in mind though that definitions of member functions for `struct A` must be under definition of `struct B`.

Comment: Clarified under "Note:".

Answer (score 2):

You can forward declare if you are returning by value.

So in your example, you'd have to do the following:

```
template <typename> struct Basic;
typedef Basic<int> B;

struct A {
    virtual B getB();
};
```

Comment: Does the compiler not need to know the size of B when returning it until it's been defined?

Comment: Only when you call `getB()`